# Angular simple weather app using openweather api error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to create a basic Angular app that shows the weather forecast for today, tomorrow and the day after tomorrow.

I have the 3 methods that are supposed to get the forecasts

```
  //Method for today's weather forecast
  getWheatherForEnschede(): Observable<any> {
    const city = 'Enschede,nl'; //Use for location
    const units = 'metric'; //Use for units metric/imperial

    const url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&units=${units}&appid=${this.api_key}`

    return this.http.get(url).pipe(
      catchError((error: any) => {
        //Print error
        console.error('Error getting the data:', error);
        return [];
      })
    );
  }

  // Method for tomorrow's weather forecast
  getTomorrowForecast(): Observable<any> {
    const city = 'Enschede,nl';
    const units = 'metric';

    // Calculate the date for tomorrow
    const tomorrowDate = new Date();
    tomorrowDate.setDate(tomorrowDate.getDate() + 1);

    const formattedDate = tomorrowDate.toISOString().split('T')[0];

    const url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=${city}&units=${units}&appid=${this.api_key}`;

    return this.http.get(url);
  }

  
  //Method for the day after tomorrow's weather forecast
  getDayAfterTomorrowForecast(): Observable<any> {
    const city = 'Enschede,nl';
    const units = 'metric';

    // Calculate the date for the day after tomorrow
    const dayAfterTomorrowDate = new Date();
    dayAfterTomorrowDate.setDate(dayAfterTomorrowDate.getDate() + 2);

    const formattedDate = dayAfterTomorrowDate.toISOString().split('T')[0];

    const url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=${city}&units=${units}&dt=${formattedDate}&appid=${this.api_key}`;

    return this.http.get(url);
  }
```

The forecast for today works, but when I request the forecast for tomorrow and the day after I get the following error in my browser console:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
   at WeatherComponent_div_1_Template (weather.component.html:15:6)
   at executeTemplate (core.mjs:11966:13)
   at refreshView (core.mjs:13461:13)
   at detectChangesInView (core.mjs:13626:9)
   at detectChangesInEmbeddedViews (core.mjs:13569:13)
   at refreshView (core.mjs:13485:9)
   at detectChangesInView (core.mjs:13626:9)
   at detectChangesInComponent (core.mjs:13601:5)    
   at detectChangesInChildComponents (core.mjs:13639:9)
   at refreshView (core.mjs:13511:13)
```

I will also add the html code maybe it will help:

```html
 <!-- Basic weather -->
<div *ngIf="weatherData">
    <h2>Weather in {{ weatherData.name }}, {{ weatherData.sys.country }}</h2>
    <p>Temperature: {{ weatherData.main.temp }}°C</p>
    <p>Conditions: {{ weatherData.weather[0].description }}</p>

    <button (click)="fetchTomorrowForecast()">Get tomorrow's Forecast</button>
    <button (click)="fetchDayAfterTomorrowForecast()">Get Day After tomorrow's Forecast</button>
  </div>
  
<!-- Tomorrow's Forecast -->
<div *ngIf="tomorrowForecast">
  <h3>Tomorrow's Forecast</h3>
  <p>Temperature: {{ tomorrowForecast?.main?.temp }}°C</p>
  <p>Conditions: {{ tomorrowForecast?.weather[0].description }}</p>
</div>

<!-- Day After tomorrow's Forecast -->
<div *ngIf="dayAfterTomorrowForecast">
  <h3>Day After Tomorrow's Forecast</h3>
  <p>Temperature: {{ dayAfterTomorrowForecast?.main?.temp }}°C</p>
  <p>Conditions: {{ dayAfterTomorrowForecast?.weather[0].description }}</p>
</div>
```

From what I noticed, if I replace the *forecast* part in the url with *weather* I no longer get an error and it works, however I always get today's weather.

From

```
const url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=${city}&units=${units}&appid=${this.api_key}`;
```

to

```
const url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&units=${units}&appid=${this.api_key}`;
```